# Check if an array of objects include any object from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an array of objects called posts and I have a comment in c1 as an array of comments by user Bob. Relationship between a post and comment is, a Post has_many Comments.

```
c1 = Comment.where(user: "Bob")
# c1 contains comment array, e.g. [#<Comment id: 23, ... >]

posts = Post.all.select{|p| p.comments.include?(c1) }
# p.comments returns comments for that post, e.g. [#<Comment id: 23, ... >]
```

If p.comments were to return one array item and c1 had one array item, as shown in comments in the code section above, comparing both values return true whereas p.comments.include?(c1) returns false. I want to filter all posts that contains the comments by Bob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `include` the associated records onto your query, then filter them accordingly:

```
Post.includes(:comments).where(comments: { user: 'Bob' })
```

Here's some more info on Rails Active Record queries

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your main task, but let me guess:

If you want to output comments from user - you need to use associations and avoid ruby code.

For example you can add something like:

```rb
class User
  has_many :commented_posts, class_name: "Post", through: :comments, sources: :commentable

# or source: :post (not sure what relation you have)
# so you can do @user.commented_posts
```